# MySQL joining table with multiple records, select latest

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table called users which has user details including a primary key called "user_id"

I then have another table called "user_transactions" and in that table I have a column called "username" (username column contains a value relating to the user_id in the "users" table). The transaction table has a column called transaction_id which is unique serial and a balance column. Not all users will have a any value in the transaction table, some will have. So what i'm looking for is basically to search for all users in the users table and show a balance column. If they dont have any balance in the transaction table then the balance should be 0. One user can also have multiple transactions in the transaction table, so it needs to take balance from the latest transaction_id matching that username

I tried something like this but it's not returning anything.

```
SELECT users.user_id, users.first_name, users.last_name, user_transactions.balance 
FROM users  
INNER JOIN user_transactions ON users.user_id=user_transactions.username
```

Any ideas how I can do this?

Thanks

Comment: `username = userid` seems highly suspicious.  Sample data and desired results might help clarify.

Comment: how should we guess how sour columns names is

Answer (score 0):

Adding the missing information and calling the date column dates

> ```
> CREATE tABLe user_transactions(userid int,dates DATeTIMe,balance DECIMAL (10.2))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO user_transactions VALUES(1,NOW(),3),(1,NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY,2)
> ```

> ```
> CREATE tABLE users(user_id int , first_name varchar(4), last_name varchar(4))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO users VALUEs (1,'test','test'),(2,'abc','abc')
> ```

> ```
> SELECT user_id, first_name, last_name, balance
> FROM
> (SELECT users.user_id, users.first_name, users.last_name, IFNULL(user_transactions.balance,0) balance
> ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY users.user_id ORDER BY user_transactions.dates DESC) rn 
> FROM users  
> LEFT JOIN user_transactions ON users.user_id=user_transactions.userid) t1
> WHERE rn = 1
> ```
>
> ```
> user_id | first_name | last_name | balance
> ------: | :--------- | :-------- | ------:
>       1 | test       | test      |       3
>       2 | abc        | abc       |       0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9b5870d70850e4ca7272bcf1729e2e7b)*